# Trocar label da aplicação fora do Manifest.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-manifest

Estou trabalhando em um projeto que será um template para vários aplicativos. 
Até agora tudo está sendo configurado via JSON.

Então surgiu a dúvida: É possível alterar esse nó abaixo fora do manifest.xml, usando talvez dentro da minha MainActivity.class? Algo como um setLabel.

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    -> android:label="@string/app_name"
```

Comment: Esta usando qual sistema de build? Gradle ou Ant?

Comment: Tou usando ant.

Comment: Ah... Se fosse Gradle, tem uma solução fácil para o problema. O ADT no Eclipse não tem suporte a `variants`, porque com `variants` encaixa perfeitamente no seu caso. Se puder migrar de uma olhada nisso.

Comment: No `ant` existe uma task para fazer replace de texto. Mas não sei se é possível alterar o `ant` do Eclipse para incluí-la. Dê uma olhada em https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html. Existe uma pergunta que dá uma pista pra modificar o build.xml que gera o apk, mas não testei: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2464725/does-the-adt-plugin-automatically-create-an-ant-build-file.

Answer (score -4):

Use o seguinte comando dentro de algum método dentro da sua classe que estende o Activity principal:

```
this.setTitle("Novo título");
```

Comment: Isso alterará apenas o título da minha Activity, mas eu quero que altere o nome do aplicativo.

Comment: Nesse caso só vai trocar o título da Activity e não da aplicação.